# How to remove a field from mongodb collection on update?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I know how to remove field from collection:

```
db.example.update({},{$unset: {field_to_del:1}},false,true)
```

But I want to delete all document fields where the length is zero when updating document.

Comment: Users edit theres profiles. And when they clear some profile field (icq number,for example) and save, at the same time, I want to document field was not just empty (sting length 0), but retired from the document.

Answer (score -2):

I think you could approach this one of two ways:

1) Know in your app which fields have been removed and remove them on update as you do in your question.

2) Script it as a batch job.  This probably does what you need: It forcibly removes any empty field (that is, empty string value) in any document in a collection (collection 'so' in this case)

```
var updateEmptyField = function(o){ 
   for (var f in o){ 
      if (o[f] === ''){ 
         eval ("db.so.update({},{$unset: {" + f + ":1}},false,true);");
      }
   }
}

db.so.find().forEach(updateEmptyField);
```

You need to use eval here to use the  variable holding the field name.